# Count the Number of Specified Tags in the First Child Node in PHP

Tags: php, html, count, domdocument

To count the number of a specified tag including nested tags, it's simple like this,

```
<?php
$html = <<<STR
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
            <li>item4</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
STR;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html );
$nodeUl->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);
echo $nodeUl->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
?>
```

But if I want to count the li tag in this case only in the first child node, how can it be achieved? I mean in this case it should be only one, not four.

Maybe remove other tags and count it? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that `getElementsByTagName()` returns all ancestor elements (with the specified tag name), rather than just children.

There are a couple of different approaches that you could take, here are two of them.

#### Loop over child nodes and count the `<li>` elements

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($nodeUl->childNodes as $child) {
    if ($child->nodeName === 'li') {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

#### Use XPath to query (and count) only child `<li>` elements

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$count = $xpath->evaluate('count(li)', $nodeUl);
```

#### Resources

- [`childNodes`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) property
- [`nodeName`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodename) property
- [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class
- [`count()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count) XPath function

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $ul) {
   $count = $ul->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
   break;
}
```